# mysql search get specific rows

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pagination

Suppose i have a variable (`$var`) that determines what rows get selected for an mysql query.The table to be searched has a date column along with some others.

- If the value of `$var = 1` then `retrieve top 5 rows in desc date order`.
- If the value of `$var = 2` then `retrieve rows 6-10  in desc date order`.
- If the value of `$var = 3` then r`etrieve rows 11-15  in desc date order`.

Comment: what is your question? You want someone to build these queries for you?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pagination+mysql+php

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    my_table
ORDER BY
    my_table.date DESC
LIMIT
   [($var - 1) * 5], 5
```

Where `[]` is where you should embed your PHP using `.` to concatenate strings if $var is between 1 and 3

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple as using the [`OFFSET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) syntax in the mysql SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT ($var*5, ($var-1)*5 +1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by date desc limit (($var-1)*5+1), ($var*5)
```